# time complexity by printing

Tags: python, printing, time-complexity

In a few days I have a test in Python.

One of the test questions is a question with running time, give us a code and ask to know what running time is.

I wanted to ask if it is possible to know what the running time is by printing something?

Because in the test we have the option to write code and debug using only prints.

question for example =

```
what is the time complexity of this code?

def func( n ):
    i=7
    j = 2**n + n
    while (i < j):
        i *= 2
        j //= 2
        c=i
        for k in range(int (c ** (1/2))):
           if (k > c**(1/4)) :
               break
```

Comment: You might be being a bit unclear in this question. In the code block you ask about `time complexity`, which you determine through the amount of loops, nested loops and such, not through timing the code. If you want to know the time it takes for the program to complete, I suggest you look at the timeit module.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter, increment it each iteration of each loop and print it.

```py
def func( n ):
    i=7
    j = 2**n + n
    ops = 1
    while (i < j):
        ops += 1
        i *= 2
        j //= 2
        c=i
        for k in range(int (c ** (1/2))):
            ops += 1
            if (k > c**(1/4)) :
               break
    print(ops)
```

Do this over a range, say 0 < n < 100 and the time complexity will be very clear. If you're still having trouble determining the time complexity, change the `print()` to a `return` and plot the values with `matplotlib` or your preferred visualization package.

```py
for i in range(100):
    func(i)
```